# DotNetBrowser WinFormsBrowserView opening in tiny window within form

Tags: winforms, dotnetbrowser

I followed the getting started tutorial for WinForms (https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000056958-quick-start-guide-for-winforms-developers).
I am using VS 2017 and .NET 4.6.1
Everything works great, but the browser window within the form is opening in a tiny window (approximately 50px square) with scrollbars and not taking up the full form.  I've been scanning SO questions and the documentation and haven't found anyone reporting this before and I have not been able to understand how to configure this.  Are there parameters for placing the control?
I tried using the 'UpdateSize' method, but that does not seem to do anything.
Has anyone else encountered this issue?
Hopefully this is a simple fix.
Thanks!  Aaron

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The BrowserView must be cast to a Control which then exposes many additional WinForm control properties such as DockStyle.

```
BrowserView browserView = new WinFormsBrowserView(BrowserFactory.Create();
Control browserWindow = (Control)browserView;
browserWindow.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
Controls.Add(browserWindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

In DotNetBrowser 1.16 and earlier versions `WinFormsBrowserView.Dock` property was set to `DockStyle.Fill` value by default.

In DotNetBrowser 1.17 and higher this property is set to `DockStyle.None` value by default.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest 1.19.1 even after replacing references multiple times.

WinFormsBrowserView does not show the .Dock property

Able to work around using this:

```
Public browser As Browser
Public browserView As BrowserView
browser = BrowserFactory.Create(BrowserType.HEAVYWEIGHT)
browserView = New WinFormsBrowserView(browser)
'browserView.dock = DockStyle.Fill  '--this will not work so instead:
Dim obj As Control    '--or Object
obj = browserView
obj.dock = DockStyle.Fill
If Controls.Contains(browserView) = False Then
    'Controls.Add(browserView)   '--Before
    Controls.Add(obj)           '--Now
```

There has to be a better solution.  Please educate me.